# How to upload bindary stream data to S3 bucket in file format using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create an AZURE PIPELINE to

1. READ BINARY STREAM DATA from SQL SERVER
2. and UPLOAD this BINARY STREAM DATA as a FILE on S3 BUCKET

I have tried COPY/DATAFLOW feature but there is no option to SINK data to S3 buckcet

**Is there any process on AZURE DATA FACTORY which is able to do that?**

Comment: As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) S3 bucket is not supported as sink in ADF

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there any process on AZURE DATA FACTORY which is able to do that?**

---

**AFAIK, we can't set Amazon S3 as sink in data factory we have to try alternate to copy file to S3.**

---

To active this I will suggest you to first copy the file from SQL server to blob storage and then use databricks notebook to copy file from blob storage to Amazon S3

- Copy data to Azure blob Storage.
  Source:
  [image]
  Destination:
  [image]
- Create notebook in databricks to copy file from Azure blob storage to Amazon S3.

**Code Example:**

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# Get file name from ADF
filename = dbutils.widgets.get("file")
# Define the Azure Blob Storage account credentials
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net", "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
# Define the S3 bucket credentials
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "<your-s3-access-key>")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "<your-s3-secret-key>")
# Define the source and destination paths
source_path = "wasbs://<container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/"+filename
Destination_path = "s3a://<your-s3-bucket-name>/<s3-destination-path>"+filename
# Copy the blob file from Azure to S3
dbutils.fs.cp(source_path, destination_path)
```

**Notebook:**
[image]

- Now, call that databricks notebook in your pipeline to copy files and create   Base parameters **file** with `filename value`.
  [image]

---

**You can raise the feature request for this sink connector [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).**